# JavaScript multiple event handler with same class input

Tags: javascript, html

I need to handle multiple event which will generate same HTML dynamically. I have added `addEventListener` for all elements. Also getting different event value.
Now i just need to set this result to this obj child `.display` element.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-box');
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    //console.log(e.target.value);
    //Method 1
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = e.target.value;
    //Method 2
    //e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.input-box {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Event Handeller</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 1</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 1 Result</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 2</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 2 Result</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 3</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 3 Result</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 4</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 4 Result</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Simply grab the `input`s instead of their parent with `document.querySelectorAll('.input-box input');` and then use `this` in your event handler `this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = this.value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `parent` and then use `querySelector` to target the sibling with class `display`

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-box');
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = e.target.value
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px;
}

.input-box {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <p>Search Box 1</p>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="display">Search Box 1 Result</div>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <p>Search Box 2</p>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="display">Search Box 2 Result</div>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <p>Search Box 3</p>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="display">Search Box 3 Result</div>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <p>Search Box 4</p>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="display">Search Box 4 Result</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use parentNode for querySelector:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-box');
inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
       //console.log(e.target.value);
       e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = e.target.value
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the `parentNode` and then use `querySelector()`

```
e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = e.target.value;
```

Or another way is to use `nextElementSibling`

```
e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = e.target.value;
```

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-box');
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.input-box {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Event Handeller</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 1</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 1 Result</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 2</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 2 Result</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 3</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 3 Result</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <p>Search Box 4</p>
    <input type="text">
    <div class="display">Search Box 4 Result</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```